# The App built using Install4j 6.0.4 is not getting uninstalled completely on Red Hat 6.4

Tags: install4j

We have an app built using Install4j on Linux. When it is being uninstalled on Linux (Red hat 6.4) it does not uninstall all the folders of jre completely. The folder bin and lib remains there and in the finish screen it gives the list of files and folders which could not be deleted. Please suggest why this issue is coming and how to resolve the same.

Comment: Probably the directories are locked at the time of the uninstallation due to an launcher that is still running.

Comment: There was no launcher running, I re-tested it. In the terminal it is giving the error like below:

Comment: There was no launcher running, I re-tested it. In the terminal it is giving the error like:   IOException:java.io.FileNotFoundException: <user_home>/Myapp/jre/lib/flavormap.properties (No such file or directory) while loading default flavormap.properties  <user_home>/jre/lib/flavormap.properties.                                                                                           But after installation I saw the flavormap.properties file present in the jre/lib directory.

Comment: What if you execute `context.registerUninstallFile(new File(context.getInstallationDirectory(), "jre/lib/flavormap.properties"));` in a "Run Script" action in the installer?

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I will try that and will let you know. But as this file is part of jre installation so it should be registered automatically like other jre files. On Windows and Mac there is no such problem seen.

Comment: Yes, definitely, it's just an experiment to see what the problem is.

Comment: The IOException for flavormap file does not come always. I tried with executing the above code through Run Script action, though the IOException related to flavormap.properties is not coming now but the warning messages for not installing some of the jre folders are still there and the folder are not getting uninstalled. I could delete the jre folder but since there is warning messages appeared on the screen so that would not help much.

Comment: You could simply remove the warning screen from the uninstaller.

Comment: I tried deleting the jre folder with "Delete file and directories" action as well as through  java code using "Run Script", but the folder is not getting deleted. Please suggest in this regard.